# Make won't locate gcc

Tags: gcc, makefile, glew, cc

I'm trying to build GLEW. But the following happens:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\glew-1.11.0>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is B0CB-4CEE

 Directory of C:\Users\User\Desktop\glew-1.11.0

13-12-2014  23:45    <DIR>          .
13-12-2014  23:45    <DIR>          ..
13-12-2014  23:44    <DIR>          auto
11-08-2014  15:14    <DIR>          bin
13-12-2014  22:48    <DIR>          build
13-12-2014  22:48    <DIR>          config
13-12-2014  22:48    <DIR>          doc
11-08-2014  15:14               276 glew.pc.in
13-12-2014  22:48    <DIR>          include
11-08-2014  15:14    <DIR>          lib
11-08-2014  15:14             3.870 LICENSE.txt
14-12-2014  00:26            13.932 Makefile
11-08-2014  15:14               591 README.txt
13-12-2014  22:48    <DIR>          src
13-12-2014  23:45    <DIR>          tmp
11-08-2014  15:14               428 TODO.txt
               5 File(s)         19.097 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  339.881.320.448 bytes free

C:\Users\User\Desktop\glew-1.11.0>make
cc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude   -o tmp/cygwin/default/shared/glew.o -c src/glew.c
make: cc: Command not found
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'tmp/cygwin/default/shared/glew.o' failed
make: *** [tmp/cygwin/default/shared/glew.o] Error 127

C:\Users\User\Desktop\glew-1.11.0>which gcc
/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin/gcc

C:\Users\User\Desktop\glew-1.11.0>gcc --version
gcc (i686-win32-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

As you can see gcc is installed. the C:\MinGW\bin folder where it's located is also in my PATH variable.

Here's the content of the Makefile:

```
#!gmake
## The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library
## Copyright (C) 2002-2008, Milan Ikits <milan ikits[]ieee org>
## Copyright (C) 2002-2008, Marcelo E. Magallon <mmagallo[]debian org>
## Copyright (C) 2002, Lev Povalahev
## All rights reserved.
## 
## Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
## modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
## 
## * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, 
##   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
## * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, 
##   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation 
##   and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
## * The name of the author may be used to endorse or promote products 
##   derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
##
## THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
## AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
## IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
## ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE 
## LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR 
## CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF 
## SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
## INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
## CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
## ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF
## THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

include config/version

SHELL = /bin/sh
SYSTEM ?= $(shell config/config.guess | cut -d - -f 3 | sed -e 's/[0-9\.]//g;')
SYSTEM.SUPPORTED = $(shell test -f config/Makefile.$(SYSTEM) && echo 1)

ifeq ($(SYSTEM.SUPPORTED), 1)
include config/Makefile.$(SYSTEM)
else
$(error "Platform '$(SYSTEM)' not supported")
endif

GLEW_PREFIX ?= /usr
GLEW_DEST ?= /usr
BINDIR    ?= $(GLEW_DEST)/bin
LIBDIR    ?= $(GLEW_DEST)/lib
INCDIR    ?= $(GLEW_DEST)/include/GL

ifneq ($(GLEW_NO_GLU), -DGLEW_NO_GLU)
LIBGLU = glu
endif

DIST_NAME     ?= glew-$(GLEW_VERSION)
DIST_SRC_ZIP ?= $(shell pwd)/$(DIST_NAME).zip
DIST_SRC_TGZ ?= $(shell pwd)/$(DIST_NAME).tgz
DIST_WIN32   ?= $(shell pwd)/$(DIST_NAME)-win32.zip

DIST_DIR := $(shell mktemp -d /tmp/glew.XXXXXX)/$(DIST_NAME)

# To disable stripping of binaries either:
#   - use STRIP= on gmake command-line
#   - edit this makefile to set STRIP to the empty string
#
# To disable symlinks:
#   - use LN= on gmake command-line

AR      ?= ar
INSTALL ?= install
STRIP   ?= strip
RM      ?= rm -f
LN      ?= ln -sf

ifneq (,$(filter debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
OPT = -g
else
OPT = $(POPT)
endif
INCLUDE = -Iinclude
CFLAGS = $(OPT) $(WARN) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS.EXTRA)

all debug: glew.lib glew.lib.mx glew.bin

# GLEW shared and static libraries

LIB.LDFLAGS        := $(LDFLAGS.EXTRA) $(LDFLAGS.GL)
LIB.LIBS           := $(GL_LDFLAGS)

LIB.SRCS           := src/glew.c
LIB.SRCS.NAMES     := $(notdir $(LIB.SRCS))

LIB.OBJS           := $(addprefix tmp/$(SYSTEM)/default/static/,$(LIB.SRCS.NAMES))
LIB.OBJS           := $(LIB.OBJS:.c=.o)
LIB.SOBJS          := $(addprefix tmp/$(SYSTEM)/default/shared/,$(LIB.SRCS.NAMES))
LIB.SOBJS          := $(LIB.SOBJS:.c=.o)

LIB.OBJS.MX        := $(addprefix tmp/$(SYSTEM)/mx/static/,$(LIB.SRCS.NAMES))
LIB.OBJS.MX        := $(LIB.OBJS.MX:.c=.o)
LIB.SOBJS.MX       := $(addprefix tmp/$(SYSTEM)/mx/shared/,$(LIB.SRCS.NAMES))
LIB.SOBJS.MX       := $(LIB.SOBJS.MX:.c=.o)

glew.lib: lib lib/$(LIB.SHARED) lib/$(LIB.STATIC) glew.pc

lib:
    mkdir lib

lib/$(LIB.STATIC): $(LIB.OBJS)
    $(AR) cr $@ $^
ifneq ($(STRIP),)
    $(STRIP) -x $@
endif

lib/$(LIB.SHARED): $(LIB.SOBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS.SO) -o $@ $^ $(LIB.LDFLAGS) $(LIB.LIBS)
ifneq ($(LN),)
    $(LN) $(LIB.SHARED) lib/$(LIB.SONAME)
    $(LN) $(LIB.SHARED) lib/$(LIB.DEVLNK)
endif
ifneq ($(STRIP),)
    $(STRIP) -x $@
endif

tmp/$(SYSTEM)/default/static/glew.o: src/glew.c include/GL/glew.h include/GL/wglew.h include/GL/glxew.h
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_STATIC $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS.SO) -o $@ -c $<

tmp/$(SYSTEM)/default/shared/glew.o: src/glew.c include/GL/glew.h include/GL/wglew.h include/GL/glxew.h
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -DGLEW_NO_GLU $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS.SO) -o $@ -c $<

# Force re-write of glew.pc, GLEW_DEST can vary

.PHONY: glew.pc

glew.pc: glew.pc.in
    sed \
        -e "s|@prefix@|$(GLEW_PREFIX)|g" \
        -e "s|@libdir@|$(LIBDIR)|g" \
        -e "s|@exec_prefix@|$(BINDIR)|g" \
        -e "s|@includedir@|$(INCDIR)|g" \
        -e "s|@version@|$(GLEW_VERSION)|g" \
        -e "s|@cflags@||g" \
        -e "s|@libname@|$(NAME)|g" \
        -e "s|@requireslib@|$(LIBGLU)|g" \
        < $< > $@

# GLEW MX static and shared libraries

glew.lib.mx:  lib lib/$(LIB.SHARED.MX) lib/$(LIB.STATIC.MX) glewmx.pc

lib/$(LIB.STATIC.MX): $(LIB.OBJS.MX)
    $(AR) cr $@ $^

lib/$(LIB.SHARED.MX): $(LIB.SOBJS.MX)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS.SO.MX) -o $@ $^ $(LIB.LDFLAGS) $(LIB.LIBS)
ifneq ($(LN),)
    $(LN) $(LIB.SHARED.MX) lib/$(LIB.SONAME.MX)
    $(LN) $(LIB.SHARED.MX) lib/$(LIB.DEVLNK.MX)
endif
ifneq ($(STRIP),)
    $(STRIP) -x $@
endif

tmp/$(SYSTEM)/mx/static/glew.o: src/glew.c include/GL/glew.h include/GL/wglew.h include/GL/glxew.h
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_MX -DGLEW_STATIC $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS.SO) -o $@ -c $<

tmp/$(SYSTEM)/mx/shared/glew.o: src/glew.c include/GL/glew.h include/GL/wglew.h include/GL/glxew.h
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_MX $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS.SO) -o $@ -c $<

# Force re-write of glewmx.pc, GLEW_DEST can vary

.PHONY: glewmx.pc

glewmx.pc: glew.pc.in
    sed \
        -e "s|@prefix@|$(GLEW_PREFIX)|g" \
        -e "s|@libdir@|$(LIBDIR)|g" \
        -e "s|@exec_prefix@|$(BINDIR)|g" \
        -e "s|@includedir@|$(INCDIR)|g" \
        -e "s|@version@|$(GLEW_VERSION)|g" \
        -e "s|@cflags@|-DGLEW_MX|g" \
        -e "s|@libname@|$(NAME)mx|g" \
        -e "s|@requireslib@|$(LIBGLU)|g" \
        < $< > $@

# GLEW utility programs

BIN.LIBS = -Llib $(LDFLAGS.DYNAMIC) -l$(NAME) $(LDFLAGS.EXTRA) $(LDFLAGS.GL)

GLEWINFO.BIN       := glewinfo$(BIN.SUFFIX)
GLEWINFO.BIN.SRC   := src/glewinfo.c
GLEWINFO.BIN.OBJ   := $(addprefix tmp/$(SYSTEM)/default/shared/,$(notdir $(GLEWINFO.BIN.SRC)))
GLEWINFO.BIN.OBJ   := $(GLEWINFO.BIN.OBJ:.c=.o)

VISUALINFO.BIN     := visualinfo$(BIN.SUFFIX)
VISUALINFO.BIN.SRC := src/visualinfo.c
VISUALINFO.BIN.OBJ := $(addprefix tmp/$(SYSTEM)/default/shared/,$(notdir $(VISUALINFO.BIN.SRC)))
VISUALINFO.BIN.OBJ := $(VISUALINFO.BIN.OBJ:.c=.o)

# Don't build glewinfo or visualinfo for NaCL, yet.

ifneq ($(filter nacl%,$(SYSTEM)),)
glew.bin: glew.lib bin
else
glew.bin: glew.lib bin bin/$(GLEWINFO.BIN) bin/$(VISUALINFO.BIN) 
endif

bin:
    mkdir bin

bin/$(GLEWINFO.BIN): $(GLEWINFO.BIN.OBJ) lib/$(LIB.SHARED)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(GLEWINFO.BIN.OBJ) $(BIN.LIBS)
ifneq ($(STRIP),)
    $(STRIP) -x $@
endif

bin/$(VISUALINFO.BIN): $(VISUALINFO.BIN.OBJ) lib/$(LIB.SHARED)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(VISUALINFO.BIN.OBJ) $(BIN.LIBS)
ifneq ($(STRIP),)
    $(STRIP) -x $@
endif

$(GLEWINFO.BIN.OBJ): $(GLEWINFO.BIN.SRC) include/GL/glew.h include/GL/wglew.h include/GL/glxew.h
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -DGLEW_NO_GLU $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS.SO) -o $@ -c $<

$(VISUALINFO.BIN.OBJ): $(VISUALINFO.BIN.SRC) include/GL/glew.h include/GL/wglew.h include/GL/glxew.h
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) -DGLEW_NO_GLU $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS.SO) -o $@ -c $<

# Install targets

install.all: install install.mx install.bin

install:     install.include install.lib install.pkgconfig

install.mx:  install.include install.lib.mx install.pkgconfig.mx

install.lib: glew.lib
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 0755 "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)"
# runtime
ifeq ($(filter-out mingw% cygwin,$(SYSTEM)),)
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 0755 "$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)"
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 lib/$(LIB.SHARED) "$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/"
else
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 lib/$(LIB.SHARED) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/"
endif
ifneq ($(LN),)
    $(LN) $(LIB.SHARED) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.SONAME)"
endif

# development files
ifeq ($(filter-out mingw% cygwin,$(SYSTEM)),)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 lib/$(LIB.DEVLNK) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/"
endif
ifneq ($(LN),)
    $(LN) $(LIB.SHARED) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.DEVLNK)"
endif
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 lib/$(LIB.STATIC) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/"

install.lib.mx: glew.lib.mx
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 0755 "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)"
# runtime
ifeq ($(filter-out mingw% cygwin,$(SYSTEM)),)
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 0755 "$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)"
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 lib/$(LIB.SHARED.MX) "$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/"
else
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 lib/$(LIB.SHARED.MX) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/"
endif
ifneq ($(LN),)
    $(LN) $(LIB.SHARED.MX) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.SONAME.MX)"
endif
# development files
ifeq ($(filter-out mingw% cygwin,$(SYSTEM)),)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 lib/$(LIB.DEVLNK.MX) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/"
endif
ifneq ($(LN),)
    $(LN) $(LIB.SHARED.MX) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.DEVLNK.MX)"
endif
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 lib/$(LIB.STATIC.MX) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/"

install.bin: glew.bin
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 0755 "$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)"
    $(INSTALL) -s -m 0755 bin/$(GLEWINFO.BIN) bin/$(VISUALINFO.BIN) "$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/"

install.include:
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 0755 "$(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR)"
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 include/GL/wglew.h "$(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR)/"
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 include/GL/glew.h "$(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR)/"
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 include/GL/glxew.h "$(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR)/"

install.pkgconfig: glew.pc
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 0755 "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)"
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 0755 "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig"
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 glew.pc "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig/"

install.pkgconfig.mx: glewmx.pc
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 0755 "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)"
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 0755 "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig"
    $(INSTALL) -m 0644 glewmx.pc "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig/"

uninstall:
    $(RM) "$(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR)/wglew.h"
    $(RM) "$(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR)/glew.h"
    $(RM) "$(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR)/glxew.h"
    $(RM) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.DEVLNK)" "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.DEVLNK.MX)"
ifeq ($(filter-out mingw% cygwin,$(SYSTEM)),)
    $(RM) "$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(LIB.SHARED)" "$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(LIB.SHARED.MX)"
else
    $(RM) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.SONAME)" "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.SONAME.MX)"
    $(RM) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.SHARED)" "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.SHARED.MX)"
endif
    $(RM) "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.STATIC)" "$(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB.STATIC.MX)"
    $(RM) "$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(GLEWINFO.BIN)" "$(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(VISUALINFO.BIN)"

clean:
    $(RM) -r tmp/
    $(RM) -r lib/
    $(RM) -r bin/
    $(RM) glew.pc glewmx.pc

distclean: clean
    find . -name \*~ | xargs $(RM)
    find . -name .\*.sw\? | xargs $(RM)

# Distributions

dist-win32:
    $(RM) -r $(DIST_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a include $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a doc $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a *.txt $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a bin $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a lib $(DIST_DIR)
    $(RM) -f $(DIST_DIR)/bin/*/*/*.pdb $(DIST_DIR)/bin/*/*/*.exp
    $(RM) -f $(DIST_DIR)/bin/*/*/glewinfo-*.exe $(DIST_DIR)/bin/*/*/visualinfo-*.exe 
    $(RM) -f $(DIST_DIR)/lib/*/*/*.pdb $(DIST_DIR)/lib/*/*/*.exp
    unix2dos $(DIST_DIR)/include/GL/*.h
    unix2dos $(DIST_DIR)/doc/*.txt
    unix2dos $(DIST_DIR)/doc/*.html
    unix2dos $(DIST_DIR)/*.txt
    rm -f $(DIST_WIN32)
    cd $(DIST_DIR)/.. && zip -rv9 $(DIST_WIN32) $(DIST_NAME)
    $(RM) -r $(DIST_DIR)

dist-src:
    $(RM) -r $(DIST_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(DIST_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(DIST_DIR)/bin
    mkdir -p $(DIST_DIR)/lib
    cp -a auto $(DIST_DIR)
    $(RM) -Rf $(DIST_DIR)/auto/registry
    cp -a build $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a config $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a src $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a doc $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a include $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a *.txt $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a Makefile $(DIST_DIR)
    cp -a glew.pc.in $(DIST_DIR)
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.o' | xargs $(RM) -r
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*~' | xargs $(RM) -r
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name CVS -o -name .cvsignore | xargs $(RM) -r
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name .svn | xargs $(RM) -r
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name "*.patch" | xargs $(RM) -r
    dos2unix $(DIST_DIR)/Makefile
    dos2unix $(DIST_DIR)/auto/Makefile
    dos2unix $(DIST_DIR)/config/*
    unix2dos $(DIST_DIR)/auto/core/*
    unix2dos $(DIST_DIR)/auto/extensions/*
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.h' | xargs unix2dos
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.c' | xargs unix2dos
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.txt' | xargs unix2dos
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.html' | xargs unix2dos
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.css' | xargs unix2dos
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.sh' | xargs unix2dos
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.pl' | xargs unix2dos
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name 'Makefile' | xargs unix2dos
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.in' | xargs unix2dos
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.pm' | xargs unix2dos
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.rc' | xargs unix2dos
    rm -f $(DIST_SRC_ZIP)
    cd $(DIST_DIR)/.. && zip -rv9 $(DIST_SRC_ZIP) $(DIST_NAME)
    dos2unix $(DIST_DIR)/Makefile
    dos2unix $(DIST_DIR)/auto/Makefile
    dos2unix $(DIST_DIR)/config/*
    dos2unix $(DIST_DIR)/auto/core/*
    dos2unix $(DIST_DIR)/auto/extensions/*
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.h' | xargs dos2unix
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.c' | xargs dos2unix
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.txt' | xargs dos2unix
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.html' | xargs dos2unix
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.css' | xargs dos2unix
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.sh' | xargs dos2unix
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.pl' | xargs dos2unix
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name 'Makefile' | xargs dos2unix
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.in' | xargs dos2unix
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.pm' | xargs dos2unix
    find $(DIST_DIR) -name '*.rc' | xargs dos2unix
    rm -f $(DIST_SRC_TGZ)
    cd $(DIST_DIR)/.. && env GZIP=-9 tar cvzf $(DIST_SRC_TGZ) $(DIST_NAME)
    $(RM) -r $(DIST_DIR)

extensions:
    $(MAKE) -C auto

.PHONY: clean distclean tardist dist-win32 dist-src
```

I'm not really knowledgeable about this stuff myself.

Comment: The Makefile seems to use `cc`, not `gcc`.  Usually you can override this easily with `make CC=gcc` but this depends on the Makefile also. Is there a `./configure` script?

Comment: `make CC=gcc` gives me alot of ouput in the form of `... redeclared without dllimport attribute: ...`, there is no `./configure script.`

Comment: When I try `make CC=gcc` it doesn't output the redeclared stuff anymore, just exactly the same error as before, saying `cc` can't be found

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. In my PATH variable, I had included both C:\MinGW\bin and C:\cygwin\bin. Removing C:\cygwin\bin did the trick. My thought process was that I should remove 1 of them, since they both contain a `make` executable.

I don't know why this worked, so if someone could exlpain, that would be nice.